# Using Core Data created in one project as input to another project

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I’ve found a couple of similar questions to this, but nothing that quite fits my needs.  I’ve developed a simple digitizing app in Swift that presents an image and allows me to digitize specific points in the image using the simulator.

I use Core Data to save the data.  One entity (“Coursemap”) has attributes for the image (Binary Data) and some meta data (Strings).  The Coursemap entity has a one-to-many relationship with a “Points” entity.  The Points entity defines attributes for the x/y coordinates for specific points in the image.  The digitizer app is working well; I can digitize and save several images using Core Data.  In the final version of my app I’ll probably need about 50-60 digitized images.

What I’d like to do is use the data from the output of my digitizer app as input to an iPad game I’m developing.  So I basically want to copy the Core Data files created in my digitizer project over to my game project so my game app can use the digitized images.  Is there a way to do this?  Is Core Data the best way to handle this?

What I’ve tried so far: I name the two projects the same, but keep them in separate folders, e.g.:
`~/digitizer/myApp and ~/games/myApp.`

The digitizer core data files are created in the folder:
`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/…/Documents.`

When I run the game app, it seems to expect the Core Data files to be in the same directory (which is why I named the two projects the same).  When the game app tries to fetch data, I get the error, “The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store”.  I’ve double-checked the data models and they are identical.

Any ideas on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure those models are identical?  Try copying the xcdatamodeld file from one project to the other.

Comment: Thanks, @pbasdf.  I'll give it a try later today and will report back.

Comment: @pbasdf Copying the xcdatamodeld file from one project to another didn't work (when I clicked on the app.xcdatamodeld file in the project navigator, nothing would appear.  I then started over and re-created my (non-digitizer) app including very carefully creating the data model, and everything is working fine now. I can run the digitizer app to create the data, then run my game app using the previously created data as input.  There was definitely something different between the data models.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, should have said to use Finder rather than Xcode Project Navigator to copy the file.  But glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I realized something similar:
- pick your prefilled sqlite file from the simulator folder
- copy it over to your other project
- during runtime, check on your other project if a sqlite structure exists and if it doesn't create it by copying the sqlite file from your bundle to the documents folder:

```
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:coreDataDatabase.path])
        {
            url = coreDataDatabase;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:url withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

            url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"];
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:url withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

            url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];

            // copy the sqlite file to /Documents/<YourApp>/StoreContent/persistentStore
            NSArray *stringParts = [kCoreDataPreloadedDatabase componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            NSString *sqlitePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    pathForResource:[stringParts objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"sqlite"];
            NSError *anyError = nil;
            BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                            copyItemAtPath:sqlitePath toPath:[url path] error:&anyError];
            if(!success)
            {
                Error(@"Unable to copy sqlite file: %@", anyError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Eike - please see my comment on my original post.  There was evidently an inconsistency between my two data models.  Thanks for posting the code; I don't know Objective-C very well but I got the gist of it.  The way I'm handling things, I won't have to do the copy programmatically.  Thanks again.